# Integrating C and Python: ValueError: module functions cannot set METH_CLASS or METH_STATIC

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, python-extensions

I am making my first venture into integrating C and Python 2.7.3. For starters, I'm just trying to write a C module for Python that can do basic addition. (It is called npfind because once I figure this out, I want to write a find method for numpy)

npfind.h:

```
#include <math.h>

extern int add(int a, int b);
```

npfind.c:

```
#include "npfind.h"

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

pynpfind.c:

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "npfind.h"

static char* py_add_doc = "Adds two numbers.";
static PyObject* py_add(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    int a, b, r;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ii", &a, &b))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    r = a + b;

    return Py_BuildValue("i", r);
}

static PyMethodDef* _npfindmethods = {
    {"add", py_add, METH_VARARGS, py_add_doc},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

void init_npfind(void)
{
    PyObject* mod;
    mod = Py_InitModule("_npfind", _npfindmethods);
}
```

npfind.py:

```
from _npfind import *

#Do stuff with the methods
```

npfindsetup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(name="npfind", version="1.0", py_modules = ['npfind.py'],
      ext_modules=[Extension("_npfind", ["pynpfind.c", "npfind.c"])])
```

After all that, on Windows 7, I type

```
python npfindsetup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=mingw32
```

Which seems to work. When I then try to find npfind.py, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "npfind.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _npfind import *
ValueError: module functions cannot set METH_CLASS or METH_STATIC
```

I cannot figure out what it is talking about. What are METH_CLASS and METH_STATIC, and why I am I trying to set them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring the `_npfindmethods` as a pointer, and trying to initialize it as an array. When I build a code copied from your snippets, I get a lot of warnings like:

```
a.c:24:5: warning: braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
a.c:24:5: warning: (near initialization for '_npfindmethods') [enabled by default]
a.c:24:5: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
a.c:24:5: warning: (near initialization for '_npfindmethods') [enabled by default]
(...)
```

The variable is initialized with an incorrect value, and thus Python finds random data inside.

---

You should declare `_npfindmethods` as an array instead:

```
static PyMethodDef _npfindmethods[] = {
    {"add", py_add, METH_VARARGS, py_add_doc},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};
```

Now it will be initialized as you expect it to. Also, because now `py_add_doc` needs to have constant address, you have to make it an array as well:

```
static char py_add_doc[] = "Adds two numbers.";
```

So, your final `pynpfind.c` would look like:

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "npfind.h"

static char py_add_doc[] = "Adds two numbers.";
static PyObject* py_add(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    int a, b, r;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ii", &a, &b))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    r = a + b;

    return Py_BuildValue("i", r);
}

static PyMethodDef _npfindmethods[] = {
    {"add", py_add, METH_VARARGS, py_add_doc},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

void init_npfind(void)
{
    PyObject* mod;
    mod = Py_InitModule("_npfind", _npfindmethods);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware there were any functional differences between pointers and arrays in C.

Comment: It's mostly about storage. Local array means that C allocates space to hold the whole array. Pointer means there's just space for memory address to an array — and then you would need to allocate the array somewhere else.

Comment: A `char**` is a pointer to (an array of) `char*`, and `char*` is a pointer to (an array of) `char`. You could say that pointers have double meaning because they can be used both to point to an array or a single element (which is basically a one-element array but with different semantics).