# Wrapper DLL for Python: "fatal error LNK1127: library is corrupt"

Tags: python, c, dll, ada, gnat

### Brief description

I have a DLL programmed in ADA with GNAT. I want to compile with MSVC another DLL in C as a wrapper to the ADA_DLL in order to use it with Python.

I have compiled the ada_DLL, then I have generated the .lib file according to [gnat documentation about MSVC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Using-GNAT-DLLs-from-Microsoft-Visual-Studio-Applications.html#Using-GNAT-DLLs-from-Microsoft-Visual-Studio-Applications). And finally I tried to compile the C_DLL with Visual-Studio, getting the error:

```
libmath.lib : fatal error LNK1127: library is corrupt
```

Update: In the case of compiling with gcc as suggested by @Brian, I get the following output:

```
>"C:\GNAT\2015\bin\gcc.exe" -c      -IC:\Python27\include -o libmath_c.o libmath_c.c
>"C:\GNAT\2015\bin\gcc.exe" -shared -LC:\Python27\libs -L./ -l libmath -o DIVISION_CPP.pyd libmath_c.o -lpython27
    .//libmath.lib: error adding symbols: Malformed archive
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

### Things I tried & more data:

I have tried importing the ADA_DLL directly with ctypes in Python and it works, so I believe that the ADA_DLL is correctly compiled. Also, forgetting about the C_DLL is not really an option.

I did a small example with a division example module. My .def file looks something like:

```
; dlltool -z libmath.def --export-all-symbols libmath.dll
EXPORTS
   [...]
    div @ 259
   [...]
```

The libmath_c.c:

```
#include "libmath_c.h"
    PyObject* _wrap_DIVISION(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
       div(10, 2);
       return Py_None;
    }
    __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl initDIVISION_CPP(void){
       Py_InitModule("DIVISION_CPP", LIB_METHODS_methods);
      }
```

The libmath_c.h:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>
PyObject* _wrap_DIVISION(PyObject *self, PyObject *args);
static PyMethodDef LIB_METHODS_methods[] = {
   { "CPP_DIVISION", _wrap_DIVISION, METH_VARARGS },
   {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}   //Added as indicated by @Brian. Thanks! 
};
__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl initDIVISION_CPP(void);
```

Any idea of what is happening? Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you can make the example an MCVE? I think that would require the Ada source (implementing division only), presumably a Python client, and build commands/Makefile. Also, would it work to build the C DLL in the same gcc version as Gnat, and only *use* it via MSVC?

Comment: I have several Python header files. What is the best way to upload an MCVE with so many "standard " header files? Yes, using gcc would be another option, I'll try it and post the results. Thanks!

Comment: gcc may be worth a try : even if it yields the same error with only C code that may help find a fix. Also, how (where) are you calling `adainit()` and `adafinal()`?

Comment: Thanks @Brian! It compiled with gcc although I'm getting import DIVISION_CPP:  ValueError: module functions cannot set METH_CLASS or METH_STATIC. Is it a must to call adainit/adafinal in the c code? In my (inherited) code there wasn't anything like that. Does it have anything to do with it?

Comment: I am not clear on adainit etc; it may happen automatically as part of the DLL framework ... or not ... for all I know, so I raised it as one thing to look into. But in any case it sounds unrelated to the METH_CLASS error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to compile with gcc+gnat but not with MSVC+gnat.

With gcc+gnat, I was getting .//libmath.lib: error adding symbols: Malformed archive. The solution consists on using libmath.dll instead of building the .lib from the .dll.

**So, in summary:**

- If you have a .dll generated by gnat, use it with gcc. You don't need to build a  .lib.
- If you have a .lib (for example python27.lib) or a .dll not generated by gnat, convert it to a .a using a tool like "pexport" (DO NOT USE SED!).
- If you really need to compile using the MSVC... I'm sorry, I could not manage to make it work. Your princess is in another castle.

Answer (score 1):

Preamble: Apologies if this turns out to be a non-answer; I want to be able to come back to this and find the links again, and comments tend to rot...

First, gcc (in the version matching Gnat) may work as an alternative C compiler, and if it does, it may eliminate difficulties with incompatible library versions.

GCC can be used for building Windows DLLs so the result should be usable from other Windows executables.

Following comments; gcc does appear to allow compilation, but the result is not currently usable from Python - here, my Python knowledge is shallow, and we don't have an MCVE, so this is speculative:

[This Q&A addresses the same error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584765/integrating-c-and-python-valueerror-module-functions-cannot-set-meth-class-or) between Python and pure C, with no Ada, suggesting this error may not be specific to C-wrapped Ada.

You have already bypassed the asker's specific error,

```
static PyMethodDef* _npfindmethods = { ... };
```

which was using a pointer; you are (correctly according to the answer) statically allocating an array. However, the accepted answer terminates the list of methods

```
static PyMethodDef _npfindmethods[] = {
    {"add", py_add, METH_VARARGS, py_add_doc},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};
```

with a NULL method; your example does not:

```
static PyMethodDef LIB_METHODS_methods[] = {
   { "CPP_DIVISION", _wrap_DIVISION, METH_VARARGS }
};
```

So my hypothesis is that when you run `setup()` on this module, it finds CPP_DIVISION successfully, then in the absence of a NULL method it runs off into the weeds, producing the same symptoms despite the difference in cause.

I could test this hypothesis using the MCVE in that question by deleting the NULL method; however I don't have a Windows system handy, only Linux.

Alternatively, I see no reason for a C layer. If there isn't one, [this Q&A addresses direct interaction between Python and Ada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271818/preventing-mangled-names-in-ada-dll?rq=1) with no C layer, though it appears to use a different method, `getattr()` to import the external method. Might be an alternative?

Comment: You were right on the "{NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}" hypothesis! :)  I'll change it in my question, as I now get a .//libmath.lib: error adding symbols: Malformed archive  with gcc similar to the original error with MS compiler.

Comment: I think making an MCVE has to be the next step - maybe you can use the linked question as a starting point and add the Ada component to it.